# Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from Rideable

Tags: java, oop, interface

```
interface Rideable { 
    String getGait(); 
}


public class Test implements Rideable {
    int weight = 2;

    String getGait() {
        return " mph, lope"; 
    }

    void go(int speed) {
        ++speed; weight++;
        int walkrate = speed * weight;
        System.out.print(walkrate + getGait());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().go(8);
    }
}
```

Why it showing the above error?

While running this I get compilation fails

What is the access specifier of the method getGait() in the Test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods declared in interface are by default `public`.

And in overriding we can only increase the scope, we cannot reduce it.

In the class where you are overriding the method, you have not mentioned `public`, so by default it considers it to be `default` (package private). So it is trying to reduce the scope and as a result you get that error.

You need to do the following,

```
@Override
public String getGait(){

}
```

Comment: No problem. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend an interface that contains a default method, you can do the following:

- Not mention the default method at all, which lets your extended
  interface inherit the default method.
- Redeclare the default method, which makes it abstract.
- Redefine the default method, which **overrides** it.

You are trying to do the last one (i.e. ***method overriding***), but to successfully do that you must keep the method signature same. Just add access specifier "**public**":

```
public String getGait() {
    return " mph, lope"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will be helpful if you brief the first two points which you mentioned.

Comment: For more info. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html.. Reclare is not same as redefine. mind it.